# I'm an hour too late for something

Tags: grammar

The phrase:
"I'm an hour too late for something"

The question:
What is more correct "an hour too late" or "too late an hour" here?

Comment: The intensifier ***too*** is irrelevant here. If an "adverb" such as *late, early, up, down, forward, back* is modified by a noun phrase (a duration, quantity, distance, etc.), and that np is placed *after* the adverb, we normally expect an intervening preposition (typically, ***by***). Thus ***I'm an hour early*** or ***I'm early by an hour*** (no preposition is needed if the np comes *before* the adverb). But in some cases we can omit the preposition with either sequence. Thus a successful gambler could say ***I'm £100 up*** or ***I'm up £100*** (as well as ***I'm up by £100***).

Comment: @WillCrawford "irrelevant" does not mean "pointless". It means, well, *irrelevant* to the discussion at hand. Nothing you say is in any sort of disagreement with anything FF said.

Comment: Touché. I'll remove it...

Answer (score 2):

I think 'an hour too late' is the more correct of the two you are asking.

Mostly because the latter 'too late an hour' would usually be phrased 'too late **by** an hour' - usually said at the point you realise you're too late.

> Oh no! I'm too late by an hour!

If mentioning the event, you wouldn't say you're 'too late by an hour for [x] so I would also change the order of things being stated for the latter.

> I'm an hour too late for [x]
>
> I'm too late for [x] by an hour